# Do I strip everything but name from the Manager's name in AD?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I cannot for the life of me, figure out what on earth I am doing wrong here.

When I run our query to pull names from Active Directory into sql server database, the output looks like this:

```
CN=Jackson\, Andrew,OU=Information Technology,OU=Departments,DC=MO,DC=canton,DC=MA,DC=us.
```

What I would like to do is trip everyting off so the output looks more like this:

```
Jackson, Andrew
```

The following code is failing me. It keeps telling me that REPLACE requires 3 arguments.

I can't seem to figure it out.

```
REPLACE(LEFT(manager,charindex('','',manager)-1),''CN='','''') as Manager
```

Comment: what's the query look like? You should be able to specify individual fields for any particular record, and not get the whole OU tree.

Comment: Well, this won't give you the exact results you want, but at least will fix your current query. You are using two quotation marks for each string (`''`), you should use one: `SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(Manager,charindex(',',Manager)-1),'CN=','') as Manager`

Comment: I am specifying individual fields. As @Jeff stated, I am not versed in Active Directory either. So, if anyone knows of a field for Manager, I am glad to use that. As for your comment Jeff, this should be just regular query. I am using OpenQuery. however, the sample query I posted is for the outer part which should be just regular query on how to use REPLACE(LEFT...(CharIndex)). I am sure there is a better of way of accomplishing what I am after.

Comment: @Lamak, your query is almost 100% correct. I am getting `Jackson\`

Any ideas how to get it to look like Jackson, Andrew?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: well, @supergrady's answer seems to work exactly as you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(<query output>,4,CHARINDEX(',OU=',<query output>) - 4),'\','')
```

This solution makes a lot of assumptions about your data, but it might work for you.

Comment: `<query output>` is the output of your AD query: `CN=Jackson\, Andrew,OU=Information Technology,OU=Departments,DC=MO,DC=canton,DC=MA,DC=us.`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding problem with the existing query, it appears that all of the double single-quotes should just be single single-quotes.

```
select REPLACE(LEFT(manager,charindex(',',manager)-1),'CN=','') as Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marc wrote in the comments, there may be a better way to do your query. I don't have experience with AD, so I won't go there.

Regarding the `REPLACE`, though, it looks like the problem is `''CN=''`. Shouldn't those be single quotation marks? In other words, it should be `'CN='`.

Comment: @bobs is right. It's not just the `''CN=''`, it's all the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\,` with a character or combination of characters that is unlikely to appear in the string, then split on `,`, then turn the special character/combination into a `,`:

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    LEFT(
      REPLACE(manager, ''\,'', CHAR(127)),
      charindex('','',REPLACE(manager, ''\,'', CHAR(127)))-1),
    ''CN='',
    ''''
  )
  , CHAR(127), '','') as Manager
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8868)